# Fixing Heroku exited with status 1, error code H10

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have attempted various resolutions; using GitHub as the deployment method, installing the NPM package serve, force cleaning cache, re-installing node_modules & package-lock.json and even switching the project from NPM to Yarn. I still get the following error.

Error log:

> 2022-01-17T16:20:29.660758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2022-01-17T16:20:29.752386+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed 2022-01-17T16:20:30.611091+00:00
> heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
> path="/" host=ip-tracker-app.herokuapp.com
> request_id=a46f3082-43fd-45e9-a049-d1076cad194f fwd="2.125.111.225"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-01-17T16:20:31.020509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
> host=ip-tracker-app.herokuapp.com
> request_id=c01ac432-ae1c-4994-9fa0-b211a8f00391 fwd="2.125.111.225"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

My Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ip-address-tracker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "*Removed for question*",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "devStart": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "*Removed for question*"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "*Removed for question*",
  },
  "homepage": "*Removed for question*",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "serve": "^13.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.8",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.6",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9"
  }
}
```

My server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const result = dotenv.config();

if (result.error) {
    throw result.error;
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening on ${PORT}.`);
});
```

I have added the following Procfile:

```
web: npm start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw an issue on your serveur if you want to serve html file like dist try this instead

```
app.use('/', serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))
```

If the purpose is to deliver image

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))
```